# Выполнение функции при нажатии кнопки / Start slide onclick button

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки функции запустилась?

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("kynney");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 300); // Change image every 0.3 sec
}
```

```css
.kynney {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="kynneyblcok" style="max-width:100px">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Например, так только по одной слайд перелистывает

```js
var myIndex = 0;
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("kynney");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 300); // Change image every 0.3 sec
}
```

```css
.kynney {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="kynneyblcok" style="max-width:100px">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: А какой эффект вы хотите получить? У вас сейчас ошибка в примере, потому что вы вызываете setTimeout(carousel, 300), а функции carousel нет. Но не понятно как по итогу должен работать код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы так реализовал, коротко и внятно...  На мой взгляд

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img'),
  button = document.querySelector('button');

let foto = [
  'https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg',
  'https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/2.jpg',
  'https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/3.jpg'
];

let i = 1;
img.src = foto[0];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (i >= foto.length)
    i = 0;
  img.src = foto[i];
  i++;
})
```

```html
<div class="kynneyblcok" style="max-width:100px">
  <img class="kynney" src="" style="width:100%">
</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос не правильно написал, пытаюсь сделать так: при запуске 1 слайд по умолчанию стоит(виден), а при нажатии кнопки запускается слайд с повтором

Comment: Так?............

Answer (score 1):

Я не стал менять вашу идею, а просто не много доработал.

Советовал бы вам другим способом решить эту задачу, ибо это не очень хороший вариант)

```js
function start() {
  let timerId;
  let animationState = 0;
  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!animationState) return;
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    animationState = 0;
    return;
  });
  return function () {
    if (animationState) return;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("kynney");
    let i;
    let myIndex = 0;

    function bust() {
      for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {
        myIndex = 1
      }
      x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      timerId = setTimeout(bust, 300);
    }
    animationState = 1;
    setTimeout(bust, 300); // Change image every 0.3 sec
    return;
  }
}

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", start());
```

```css
.kynney {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="kynneyblcok" style="max-width:100px">
  <img class="kynney active" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="kynney" src="https://blognumbers.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/3.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
<button id="start">Click me</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: А можно сделать так чтобы 1 слайд уже был виден при запуске?

Comment: @АндрейЗахаров, сделал коррективы, но это своего рода костыль. Я бы вам посоветовал реализовать другим способом задачу, так как я просто внес коррективы.